# VBA SQL Sum- group by statement only takes up to two digit decimalvalue

Tags: sql, vba, group-by, sum, decimal

I am having issue with SQL statement within VBA.

I have a dataset that has one column with value up to 3 digit decimal, like this:

```
Name    Value  
---------------
A       0.004  
B       0.005  
A       0.123  
C       0.533
```

I want to write a SQL statement in VBA that sum up **Value** based on **Name**

like this:

```
sql = select name, sum(value) from data.csv group by name
```

Right now my problem is that when I do the sum up, excel only seems to take up to 2 digits **to sum**, meaning A 0.004 would be 0 and A 0.123 would be 0.12. The result is that I have missed some value in the summation process :

My desired result would be

```
A  0.127  (0.003 + 0.124)  
B  0.005  
C  0.533
```

But instead now I am getting

```
A  0.12  (0 + 0.12)  
B  0  
C  0.53
```

What should I do in this situation to fix the issue?

I have tried sum(cdbl(value)) but it did not work.

Thank you so much!

EDIT: My specific code is as follow:

```
Sub Createnewfile()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String

FName = "\new file.xlsx"
FPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & FName

If Not Dir(FPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then Kill FPath

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath
Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

cn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"""
cn.Open

sql = "SELECT Name, sum(cbdl(value)) as value " & _
      "FROM data.csv " & _
      "GROUP BY Name "

rs.Open sql, cn
For c = 0 To rs.Fields.count - 1
    wsData.Cells(1, c + 1).Value = rs.Fields(c).Name
Next

rs.MoveFirst
r = wsData.UsedRange.Rows.count + 1
wsData.Cells(r, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
cn.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With Workbooks("new file.xlsx")
    .Save
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: please include your code and is a pivottable not an option? Is this Excel?

Comment: Do you need to adjust the number formatting in Excel to display additional decimal digits?

Comment: My psudo code is shown above. The data file is csv and this new file that I am trying to compile is xlsx, could this be the reason?

Comment: Could you explain more regarding the number formatting? The data file that contains 3 digits demical is csv and I am trying to create a new xlsx file using SUM - group by statement.  Thank you!